# Debian KVM bridge promiscuous mode still has IP

Tags: kvm-virtualization, bridge, promiscuous

I had three interfaces working on my Debian KVM box, all three bridged to guest VM's, f0 was mgmt, f1 was public static, and f2 was working promisc bridge. When I reinstalled the OS on larger drive and ported my /etc/networking/interfaces back in, my promisc br2 bridge comes up with an IP for some reason, even though I set it to 0.0.0.0 in interfaces like:

```
# The primary network interface
auto ens2f0
iface ens2f0 inet manual
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
   address 1.2.3.4/24
   gateway 1.2.3.1
   bridge_ports ens2f0
   bridge_fd 9
   bridge_hello 2
   bridge_maxage 12
   bridge_stp off

auto ens2f1
iface ens2f1 inet manual
auto br1
iface br1 inet static
    address 5.6.7.8/24
    gateway 5.6.7.1
    bridge_ports ens2f1
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp off

auto ens2f2
iface ens2f2 inet manual
auto br2
iface br2 inet static
    address 0.0.0.0
    bridge_ports ens2f2
    up /sbin/ifconfig br2 promisc on
```

So now my ip a on the promisc bridge looks like:

```
4: ens2f2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br2 state UP group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:1e:67:7c:84:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: br2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:1e:67:7c:84:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 7.8.9.10/8 brd 7.255.255.255 scope global br2
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 fe80::21e:67ff:fe7c:842d/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How do I make by br2 not have an IP again so it will port information from the mirror port to my guests? I have installed the bridge-utils package.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out, the bridge interface for the mirror only needs a couple lines, so delete the rest and make it look like this:

```
auto ens2f2
iface ens2f2 inet manual

auto br2
iface br2 inet static
    address 0.0.0.0
    bridge_ports ens2f2
```